# How can I get Rid of extra characters in eclipse c++ editor

Tags: c++, eclipse, editor

I use eclipse c++ indigo. In the editor there are two types of extra inactive and non-selectible characters. 
I want to get rid of these circled characters shown in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You can check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 'show whitespace characters' turned on. There is a toggle on the tool bar to turn this off:
[image]

You can also turn this on/off and configure what is shown in the Preferences on the 'General > Editors > Text Editors' page.